# How to render audio waveform on HTML5 canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I want to render a waveform for an audio file (ogg and/or mp3) to a canvas element.

I was wondering if there were any libraries that would make this simple? I am looking for a result along these lines: http://plucked.de/

Answer (score 27, accepted):

https://github.com/katspaugh/wavesurfer.js may be what you're looking for.

Comment: Do you know how to use it without have to wait the waves appear before you can play the song ? It is really slower :/ (Look at my website test : [link](http://patrickcosta.webs.com/index.html)

Comment: No I don't, I hope you found a way! I ended up working on another project.

Comment: Any OSS alternatives? The above is released under Creative Commons 3…

Comment: @AinTohvri Not that I know of, if you find anything please share

Comment: @nak what if the audio source was microphone instead of a file? would wavesurfer still work?

Answer (score 8):

If you don't want to download content of the file then waveform image or data must be prepared on server.

Some time ago BBC (yes, UK media company) open-sourced set of tools to do it efficiently. All is described on their blog: http://www.bbc.co.uk/rd/blog/2013/10/audio-waveforms

Shortly: on Linux server-side you have to convert sound file (FLAC, WAV or MP3) to JSON-based waveform interpolation with [audiowaveform](https://github.com/bbcrd/audiowaveform) command-line tool. Next you serve the JSON data to browser client which will render waveform on canvas element with [waveform-data.js](https://github.com/bbcrd/waveform-data.js).