# JS How to render audio waveform without any plugins?

Tags: javascript, audio, canvas

I just need to render a simple waveform on my HTML5 canvas. And it's important for me to have opportunities to modify drawing loop (for every second).

Comment: Think this is a duplicate of another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12234222/how-to-render-audio-waveform-on-html5-canvas

Comment: Also, check this out. http://www.waveformjs.org/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to render audio waveform on HTML5 canvas?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12234222/how-to-render-audio-waveform-on-html5-canvas)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you are looking for: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API/Visualizations_with_Web_Audio_API#Creating_a_waveformoscilloscope